# What is instant-run file on Android?

Tags: android, file, android-studio, instant-run

When I run the app in Android Studio and I see all app's files (fileList()) there is instant-run file. What is this file?? I delete it and nothing changes.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AefJXhCxrK8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a feature of Android Studio introduced in the version 2.0. It quickly swaps new codes with old ones and enables us to see the result almost immediately. As side products of this process, IDE might produce some files, but you should not worry about them.

> ... Instant Run is a behavior for the Run and Debug  commands that significantly reduces the time between updates to your app. Although your first build may take longer to complete, Instant Run pushes subsequent updates to your app without building a new APK, so changes are visible much more quickly. ...

See here for details: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

Comment: Thanks you so much!!